# Reflexive, Symmetric, and Transitive. How to read?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm a little confused on these problems as far as the wording goes. I know how to tell if one is reflexive, symmetric, or transitive.

The way the problem is set up is:

```
A= the set of all positive integers. R = {(x,y)} | x and y are prime
```

Do I strictly use prime numbers to test this out?

OR could I use 1 since it says " The set of all positive integers" and 1 is a positive integer?

How could I read this to make it "easier" to understand?

Comment: The underlying set is the set of positive integers. That makes the relation not reflexive, since for example $R$ does not contain the pair $(4,4)$, or $(1,1)$. For the other properties, you will in effect be able to focus on primes only, though in principle you are still working with all positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ acts on the set of positive integers, so reflexivity requires that every positive integer relates to itself, or for $x \in A, R(x,x)$. Hopefully, you can find a counterexample.

Similarly, symmetry requires that for all $x,y \in A, R(x,y) \to R(y,x)$, and transitivity is defined as usual, acting on all elements on $A$. From there, you should be able to tell why $R$ is transitive and symmetric.

Comment: therefore it is not reflexive for (1,1). It is symmetric because if x&y are prime Y&x are prime and it is transitive

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.